# Stenciljs: Won't parse JSON data in an API fetch request

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic5, stenciljs

For context I am pretty new to stencil and Ionic. However I am getting an error when attempting to parse the JSON data and `console.log` it.

ERROR

```
-card01.tsx:34 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at my-card01.tsx:34:33)
    at MyCard01.handleSubmit (my-card01.tsx:34:33)
```

My Code:

```
import { Component, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-card01',
  styleUrl: 'my-card01.css',
  shadow: false,
})
export class MyCard01 {
  @Prop() cardTitle: string;
  @Prop() cardSubtitle: string;
  @Prop() cardContent: string;

  textInput!: HTMLInputElement;

  async handleSubmit(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userIDGathered = this.textInput.value;
    const userIDSTR = userIDGathered.toString();
    console.log(userIDSTR);

    // get data from api using fetch
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${userIDSTR}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    });

    console.log(response);

    // conver the response to json
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>{this.cardTitle}</ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle>{this.cardSubtitle}</ion-card-subtitle>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-input autofocus placeholder="Enter a user ID here" color="tertiary" type="text"ref={(el) => (this.textInput = el as unknown as HTMLInputElement)}></ion-input>
          <ion-button fill="solid" type="submit" color="secondary" onClick={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>Submit</ion-button>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    );
  }
}
```

`console.log for response`

[image]

also the API is a just a express app with that one route since I am still learning stencil.

EDIT: I suspect its something to do with the way the input data is handled but I don't know what or why.

Answer (score 1):

Had to fix CORS policy on the API

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});
```

Also the this.textInput wasnt originally making it to the userIDGathered point

so fixed that with

```html
<ion-input 
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a user ID"
        value={this.textInput}
        onIonChange={event => this.textInput = event.detail.value} 
        />
        <ion-button type="submit" fill="solid" color="success" size='default' onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()}>Submit</ion-button>
```